# Pestaña eliptica

Tags: css, css3, formas

Buena tarde a toda la comunidad.

Existe forma de realizar esta pestaña solo con CSS?

[image: Pestaña]

He intentado utilizar un circulo como base y en after y before igual, circulos pero no puedo obtener la forma correcta.

```
.scroller {
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -40px;
        background-color: $secondary;
        border-radius: 100%;
        &:before {
            content: '';
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            border-radius: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            left: -30px;
            bottom: -18px;
            border: 40px solid rgba($secondary, 0.5);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola Itzli, sería ideal que añadieras también el código HTML (y el CSS generado por SASS), de ese modo podremos ayudarte con tu problema específico. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Primero, necesitas un contenedor que oculte la parte inferior del círculo. La barra azul no puede porque si oculta el overflow lo haría tanto hacia abajo como hacia arriba.

Segundo, sea lo que sea `$secondary` no puede ser un color plano porque luego lo usas como rgba que espera 3 números separados por comas.

El siguiente ejemplo tiene un círculo hecho con puro CSS, donde no está el spline de tu imagen y la unión del círculo acá es en la práctica una esquina.

Después puse un ejemplo usando un path SVG, que ya es más elaborado. Pero tú lo podrías hacer incluso con una imagen de fondo.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.scroller {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  overflow-y: show;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
.container > b {
position:relative;
left:5px;
top:15px;
}
.circle.scroller:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#svgbg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 18px;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 17px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -50px;
  opacity: 1;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  fill-rule: evenodd;
  stroke: none;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  stroke-dasharray: none;
  stroke-opacity: 1
}

.chevrondown {
  margin: auto;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 38px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.chevrondown:hover {
  fill: red;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.clip-svg {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  height: 0;
}

.clippath_member {
  fill-opacity: 1;
  fill-rule: nonzero;
  stroke: none;
}

.scroller.clipped {
  height: 45px;
  clip-path: url(#bezier_clip_path);
}
```

```html
<svg class="clip-svg">
    <defs>
      <path
        id="path2"
        class="clippath_member"
        d="M 0,18 H 100 V 17 H 99.98991 C 79.35169,17 70.004651,0 50.549894,0 31.095137,0 18.262537,17 0.100898,17 H 0 Z"
      />
      <rect
        id="rectangulo"
        width="100%"
        height="55"
        x="0"
        y="17"
        class="clippath_member"
      />
      <clipPath id="bezier_clip_path">
        <use href="#path2" x="50%" transform="translate(-50,0)" />
        <use href="#rectangulo" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
  <div class="container" style=" top: 0;">
   <b>Yo uso un seudoselector</b>
    <a class="chevrondown">⌵</a>
    <div class="scroller circle">
    
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style=" top: 66px;">
  <b>Yo uso un svg inline</b>
    <a class="chevrondown">⌵</a>
    <div class="scroller">
      <svg id="svgbg" viewBox="0 0 100 18">
        <use xlink:href="#path2" fill="#0000ff"></use>
      </svg>
    </div>
    
  </div>

  <div class="container" style=" top: 131px;">
    <b>Yo uso un clip path svg</b>

    <a class="chevrondown">⌵</a>
    <div class="scroller clipped"></div>
  </div>
```

<s>Nótese que el chevron-down lo pongo en otro seudoselector, dado que si fuera el content del círculo no podrías modificar su posición vertical exactamente a tu gusto</s>

Edit 1: puse el chevron down como link, es más fácil de manipular.

**Edit 2**: el spline en la unión lo hice con SVG, no es de lo más conveniente y es mejor usar un editor como inkscape.

**Edit 3**: dejé un tercer ejemplo usando clip-path.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. En efecto $secondary es un color, estoy utilizando SASS, lo que no he podido solucionar es dar el efecto ondulado a los laterales del circulo. Si ves la imagen, no es un semicirculo, sino que tiene una especie de curvas.

Comment: Hice las curvas con un SVG. ejecuta mi snippet ahora

Comment: La opción de SVG va a ser la mejor en este caso (hasta que los navegadores den soporte a clip-path con un path). Si quieres tener el código HTML más limpio, puedes poner el SVG como imagen de fondo inline en CSS.

Comment: Muchas gracias!
Funcionó muy bien

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro agregué una solución con clip-path, pero requiere un par de trucos para manipular el posicionamiento y no uso directamente el path sino una composición de éste y un rectángulo

Comment: @amenadiel creo que la opción con path me parece mejor. Estoy por poner una solución solo en CSS usando clip-path... el problema es que aunque es estándar sólo la soporta un navegador (Firefox)... y solo desde ayer.

Comment: Dale! Se define vectorial directo en el css?

Comment: @amenadiel en la definición del estándar está, pero los navegadores no lo soportan. Sólo permiten poner polígonos o imágenes, pero no un path en sí.